# SQL Case Update to two different column based on select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform what I believe a very simple case-update SQL to two different column based on a select:

`PROD_TB`:

```
Product_Code   Reg_Price     Sale_Price
     A           1000           2000
```

`PRICE_TB`:

```
Product_Code   Type    Price
     A         REG     3000
     A         SALE    4000
```

Desired update result:

`PROD_TB`:

```
Product_Code   Reg_Price     Sale_Price
     A           3000           4000
```

What I attempted:

```
UPDATE PROD_TB
SET Reg_Price = CASE 
                   WHEN PRICE_TB.Type = 'REG' 
                     THEN PRICE_TB.Price 
                     ELSE Reg_Price 
                END, 
    Sale_Price = CASE 
                    WHEN PRICE_TB.Type = 'SALE' 
                      THEN PRICE_TB.Price 
                      ELSE Sale_Price 
                 END
FROM 
    PROD_TB
JOIN 
    PRICE_TB ON PROD_TB.PRODUCT_CODE = PRICE_TB.PRODUCT_CODE
```

Running the above SQL only updates regular price, not the sale price. Does SQL not support these types of update query? Or did I make an elementary mistake?

Comment: You need to remove second `set` and use the `,` instead of that.

Comment: you should only use one "set", like: update table set col1=a, col2=b, col3=c ...

Comment: Woops. My mistake on creating simple example. Fixed

Comment: also the join logic there isnt right. You'll most probably have to use two joins for the values. Or subqueries instead.

Comment: I guess REG and SALE types will always exist for same product code in PROD_TB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? Basically, just join the set from the PRICE_TB on the condition of which column you want to get from it.

But this is assuming you will only ever have one PRICE_TB.TYPE per updated PROD_TB column name, and that each PROD_TB column always contains a value in PRICE_TB, otherwise it'll be NULL and that row won't be returned. So make sure you know the variations of data that can exist here.

```
UPDATE PROD
SET Reg_Price = REG.Price, Sale_Price = SALE.Price
FROM PROD_TB PROD
JOIN PRICE_TB REG ON REG.Product_Code = PROD.Product_Code AND REG.Type = 'REG'
JOIN PRICE_TB SALE ON SALE.Product_Code = PROD.Product_Code AND SALE.Type = 'SALE'
```

Comment: Incredibly stupid of me.. this somehow slipped off my mind.. Thanks I'll accept in a few minutes

Comment: Happens to the best of us, no worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the data into one row first, here's example that fetches always the biggest price, in case there's more than one in PRICE_TB, otherwise it should work the same way as @Kahn's sql.

```
UPDATE 
  PROD
SET 
  PROD.Reg_Price = PRICE.Reg_Price,
  PROD.Sales_Price = PRICE.Sales_Price
FROM PROD_TB PROD, cross apply (
  select 
    max(CASE WHEN Type = 'REG' THEN Price ELSE 0 end) as Reg_Price,
    max(CASE WHEN Type = 'SALE' THEN Price ELSE 0 end) as Sale_Price
  from
    PRICE_TB PRICE
  where
    PRICE.Product_Code = PROD.Product_Code
) PRICE
```

Comment: if there is a third type in table PRICE_TB and no other matching rows, this will set the value of the prices to 0. Not sure this is what is needed. Hidden feature perhaps. Negative values will also be set to 0. Unlikely that happens, but still can't rule out anything without knowing the business logic

Answer (score 0):

If your table PRICE_TB doesn't always contain both values, you could use this to make sure the table is updated anyway:

```
UPDATE t1
SET 
  Reg_Price = coalesce(t2.Price, t1.Reg_Price),
  Sale_Price = coalesce(t3.Price, t1.Sale_Price)
FROM PROD_TB t1
LEFT JOIN
  PRICE_TB t2
ON 
  t1.ProductCode = t2.ProductCode AND
  t2.[Type] = 'REG'
LEFT JOIN
  PRICE_TB t3
ON 
  t1.ProductCode = t3.ProductCode AND
  t3.[Type] = 'SALE'
WHERE 
  t2.[Type] = 'REG' OR
  t3.[Type] = 'SALE'
```